# Python - Matrix IndexError exception not working

Tags: python, matrix, indexing

I am trying to write a function which enables a move 1 unit to the left (in the x-axis) in a grid. It should only work if there is a valid coordinate to the left, and if not (i.e. the start point is on the edge of the grid), the function should return `None`. Here is my attempt:

```
def left_move(point):
    try: 
        LEFT = grid[point[1]][point[0]-1]
    except IndexError: 
        return None
    if LEFT == '.':
        change = [-1,0]
        for idx, amount in enumerate(change):
            point[idx]+=amount
        return point
    return None
```

Say the starting point is `[0,3]` and therefore on the edge of the grid and I only run the top part of the code:

```
def left_move(point):
    try: 
        LEFT = grid[point[1]][point[0]-1]
    except IndexError: 
        return None
```

It returns `None` as expected. But if the whole block is executed it returns `[-1,3]` which is outside of the grid and shouldn't be allowed by the `try-except` . Why is this? And how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Python's interpretation of `-1` in array indexing is the last element of the array. `-1` is a legal way of referencing array elements and thus will not trigger an `IndexError` exception.

```
>>> a = [0,1,2]
>>> print a[-1]
2
```

You would need to manually check if the value you are given resolves to `-1` and then handle that accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you need to place the rest of the code inside the try statement. Otherwise, it will try, fail, and then run the rest of the code.

```
def left_move(point):
    if point[0]-1 != -1: 
        LEFT = grid[point[1]][point[0]-1]
        if LEFT == '.':
            change = [-1,0]
            for idx, amount in enumerate(change):
                point[idx]+=amount
            return point
        return None
    else: 
        return None
```

Comment: The code yields the same result whether the `if` statement is within the `try` block or not. If there is an exception then the function will `return None` and not execute the rest of the block.

Comment: ahh yes now I see, you need to refer to Jokab's answer, but its because -1 is a valid index in python. I replaced the try/except with a simple if statement, it should do the same. The reason the code was working when you only had the try/except was because the code would finish with no problem, and not find a return statement so simply returned None by default, or at least thats my guess. @ggordon

Comment: Yes replacing the `try-except` with `if` is a good idea, thanks!